# Bootstrap Collapsible Navbar won't collapse

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to using frameworks and I'm using bootstrap for a class project and trying to get this navbar to create the buttons when I collapse it but it doesn't create the button when the browser is collapsed, any ideas?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>JavaJam Coffee House</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="javajam.css" type="text/css">

</head>`
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="nav">
    <div id="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"> 
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">JavaJam</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="menu.html">Menu</a></li>
                    <li><a href="music.html">Music</a></li>
                    <li><a href="jobs.html">Jobs</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>    
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content">


    <ul>
      <li>Specialty Coffee and Tea</li>
      <li>Bagels, Muffins, and Organic Snacks</li>
      <li>Music and Poetry Readings</li>
      <li>Open Mic Night</li>
    </ul>


    </div>
    <div id="footer"> JavaJam Coffee House • 12312 Main Street Mountain Home, CA 93923 • 1-888-555-5555 • Copyright © 2014<br>
    <a href="mailto:alexsbarrington@gmail.com">alexsbarrington@gmail.com</a></div>
</div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am sure that : <div id="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" should actually be 'class' instead of 'id'

Comment: Yep that totally worked, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change  ID to Class and it will work. General rule only have 1 ID per element.

Comment: Yeah it worked I just messed up in my syntax, thank you!